# Sending bytes via UDP packets without further conversion

Tags: python, sockets, udp, byte

I have a program that needs to be sent very specific strings of bytes via UDP. I ended up with a short program a bit like this (python2.7, the 3.2 version just uses b'' to convert as required) to send the bytes:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
        socket.SOCK_DGRAM)     

UDP_IP = "101.101.101.101" #Target IP Address
UDP_PORT = 1010

#Create a socket    
def sendPacket(MESSAGE):
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #Send message to UDP port

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sendPacket('5f00000001000701cc0000001f8b')
```

However, while this would be interpreted by another Python socket as the correct value, Wireshark picks up the value differently (below). Repeating this using Perl, I have the same problem:

```
35 66 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 37 
30 31 63 63 30 30 30 30 30 31 66 38 62
```

This must mean that the string of bytes is being further converted in a byte array when it already is in that format! The question therefor is, how can I send a byte stream so it arrives with the same data as it started with?

Comment: It looks like an ASCII string to me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is sending exactly what you requested. Try:

```
sendPacket('\x5f\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x07\x01\xcc\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b')
```

Comment: That'd be why. I've completely missed the obvious here!